# MYSQL - How to find records within a date range

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The table I'm looking at has columns with fixed dates - `EnteredDateTime` and `AuditDateTime`.  I need some help finding records that are older than 1 day and less than 7 days old

The code I'm using at the moment is -

`EnteredDateTime BETWEEN DATE_ADD(AuditDateTime, INTERVAL 1 day) AND DATE_ADD(AuditDateTime, INTERVAL 7 day)`

Comment: So why is auditdatetime part of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what is the problem with your current query? Do you want `older than 1 day and less than 7 days` from today's date? If so, use `DATE_SUB` and `NOW()`:

```
EnteredDateTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)
                    AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)
```

Or if one of the columns answer this condition?

```
EnteredDateTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)
                    AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)
OR  AuditDateTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)
                      AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)
```

You can use `GREATEST()` or `LEAST()` if you know which one of the dates you want to check against (lowest or highest) to avoid the use of `OR` .